# Python object to JSON but only selected attributes

Tags: python, json, flask, sqlalchemy

I am trying to make my object from and to JSON. This object uses SQL Alchemy so using `json.dumps(vars(self))` doesnt work. I am looking for the syntax to make this possible.

```
    def to_json(self):
        obj = {
            self.won,
            self.gameOver,
            self.allowMultiColor,
            self.pattern,
            self.board,
            self.round,
            self.totalRounds
        }

        return json.dumps(obj)
```

And then I want to redefine fields like this:

```
    def from_json(self, json_string):
        obj = json.loads(json_string)

        self.won = obj['won']
        self.gameOver = obj['gameOver']
        self.allowMultiColor = obj['allowMultiColor']
        self.pattern = obj['pattern']
        self.board = obj['board']
        self.round = obj['round']
        self.totalRounds = obj['totalRounds']
```

the `to_json` method doesnt' work. And when I try to get it again I get this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

I am new to python so I don't yet know all the fancy syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obj must to be a dictinary to allow using strings as indices.
So obj should look like this

```
obj = {
            'won':self.won,
            'gameOver':self.gameOver,
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Ah, so it was the syntax I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can pass sqlalchemy objects into marshmallow's scheme, defining it's attributes into marshmallow's scheme. no problem with it.